# dpkg --purge error (won't resolve in aptitude) fixable in apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Does one have to erase files in  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`  in order to get rid of "package is in a very bad inconsistent state" ? It seems so! Will every subprocess error exit status 5 cause this problem?

I've exhausted all package tools that there are for Ubuntu and always run into a dpkg error. Since those tools all break early, there is no way to fix the situation. The dreaded **aptitude** TUI goes in endless loop and synaptic quits immediately with a cryptic error, not allowing to operate anyhow. At the core lies this:

```
$ LANG=en sudo   dpkg --force-all    --purge    'brmfc7440nlpr:i386' 
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 455581 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing brmfc7440nlpr:i386 (2.0.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package brmfc7440nlpr:i386 (--purge):
 installed brmfc7440nlpr:i386 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5

Errors were encountered while processing: brmfc7440nlpr:i386
```

synaptic and such, which just call dpkg are of no use here. Can one set  APT::Variables or whatever to fix it? Does one always have to delete files from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`? The synaptic breakage seems intentional.

Comment: LANG=en sudo      dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq   'brmfc7440nlpr:i386' 

### breaks just the same. --remove or --purge seem to make no real difference in this situation.

Comment: neither does reducing --force-all

Comment: dpkg --force-all --purge 'brmfc7440nlpr:i386'  ### works only after manually ERASING all offending packages from /var/lib/dpkg/info/   and then some. I removed all brother stuff I could find. After that, the installer-bash-script by "brother" could reinstall the laserprinter driver again. It would not catch that dpkg error either. synaptic instructs the user to report the error, so seemingly synaptic works as intended leaving the user in limbo.

Comment: What is the result when you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then aftrward run `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing` and finish with `sudo apt-get install -f` from terminal?

Comment: the root problem is fixed by now, so one never knows the answer. I am almost certain though, that your suggestion won't work either, with breakage by dpkg just like above with synaptic. it can't fix the missing package because it is not in a repo, since its sideloaded from file rather than a ubu-repo via internet. neither install nor remove did work, you see.

Comment: concerning above error msg: "package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5 " # since I deleted that post-removal script in   var lib dpkg info , I guess,  dpkg breakage no longer occurred. in apt , the hard work always is cut out for the user rather than a package manager.

Comment: I assume that the trouble with package brmfc7440nlpr:i386 started because Ubuntu package LPRng and the official MFC laser-printer installer by "Brother Inc." fight over the lp configuration and mess up each others stuff. I am not feeling like repeating the experience just to find out about apt, however. Maybe some other Brother user may want to try  ;-)   Recent Brother "MFC" machines (Multi Function Copier) claim compatibility with LPRng.